# Path where user extracted php files to

Tags: php

If a user extracted the files of my php application to example `http://example.com/test/webapp/`, the absolute links in my application won't work anymore.

How can I get the path `/test/webapp/` to add it to my absolute links?

Comment: You need `dirname(__FILE__)` and subtract the base `DOCUMENT_ROOT` from it.

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` does the same as `__DIR__`, which is returning the server path, not the relative uri path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with:

```
dirname( $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] );
```

make sure your links are always **relative** in your pages, so when you move your site to another domain they still work.

Check out all other `$_SERVER` variables by executing `phpinfo()` .

for redirecting, you can use:

```
header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) . '/some_page.php');
```

Comment: I got relative links of course. But when using the `Location: ` header, I need to use a absoluteURI.

Comment: @Zulakis Ok, I've updated my answer with an example to redirect based on the $_SERVER variables for paths.

Comment: Yeah, I already had that, but thanks :-) I was just commenting on your relative links statement.

Comment: But another question, if the script itself is in a subdirectory, what am I'm going to do then?

Comment: Just append it to the page to redirect like '/my_subdir/some_page.php'

Comment: What I mean is that `dirname( $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] );` will return something like `/test/webapp/my_subdir/` then

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but it's not a full solution. It gives you the relative path, but it's not guaranteed that you can add that. `/documents` and `/documents/index.php`, may both point to the same script, but cannot both be used to just add a relative path to. I think it's best to make it a setting, which the user may configure.